# How can I get the value before a monetary word in a string with R?

Tags: r, string, text

An apology in advance if this is very basic!

I have the following string:

```
text <- "Odebrecht has admitted to paying $29 million in bribes to public officials in Peru between 2005 and 2014 in exchange for $12.5 billion in contracts."
```

How can I get the amounts before the word "million" and "billion"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html (in R, needs the `perl` argument to be `TRUE`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `stringr` solution, using lookarounds and a regular expression. I match non-space characters `\\S` and a space  that are followed by `million` or `billion`.

```r
text <- "Odebrecht has admitted to paying $29 million in bribes to public officials in Peru between 2005 and 2014 in exchange for $12.5 billion in contracts."

library(stringr)
text %>%
  str_extract_all("\\S*? (?=(million|billion))", simplify = TRUE) %>%
  str_trim()
#> [1] "$29"   "$12.5"
```

Created on 2018-03-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any way to preserve the word "million" or "billion" itself?

Comment: Change `(?=(million|billion))` to just `(million|billion)` I would read up on how regular expressions works too. Here is a [good resource](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html).